# Javascript loop to create multiple divs appended to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is making my head spin a bit.

I am trying to dynamically create slider items. There is always at least one slide, so I've added in `#portfolio-slide-1` into the code to represent the first slide.

When the user clicks on a particular item in the portfolio, data from another file is loaded in using jQuery `.load()` into `#portfolio-slide-1` and then the screen navigates to that element.

Now the next bit, I need to do the same for any other slides. For example, if this particular portfolio item has a total of `3` slides, then I need to create two more. That's the default `#portfolio-slide-1` plus `#portfolio-slide-2` and `#portfolio-slide-3`. I then need to `.load()` the content into those sliders so it's sitting there waiting to be viewed.

Here is the code for loading data into `#portfolio-slide-1` (which always exists)

#### HTML

```
<div class="grid half portfolio-item" id="dorking-brewery" data-number-slides="2">
<div class="slide" id="portfolio-slide-1"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.portfolio-item').click(function(){
        var portfolioItem = $(this).attr('id'); // dorking-brewery
        $('#portfolio-slide-1').load('pages/'+portfolioItem+'-1.php', function( {}); // loads the content from pages/dorking-brewery-1.php into the slide
        $('#portfolio-slide-1').addClass(portfolioItem); // adds a specific classname like dorking-brewery
        $('#portfolio-slide-1').addClass(portfolioItem+'-1'); // adds a specific classname like dorking-brewery-1
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight(); // animates the slider to slide right.
    });
```

This all works fine.

However now I need to create those extra slides. I have added a data attribute to the clickable item `data-number-slides="2"` in this example. So this portfolio item needs the default slide, and one extra.

I now need to create `#portfolio-slide-2`

So I extract the `data` number of how many slides:

```
var numberSlides = $(this).data('number-slides');
```

Then I check to see if the number of slides is more than 1, it is, so I need to create the extras:

```
if(numberSlides > 1){...};
```

**And now this is where I am stuck**. I need to write a loop that creates the extra slides needed. So in this case `numberSlides = 2` so only one extra is needed. But if `numberSlides = 4` then 3 would need to be created and so-on. They would have to be added *after* `#portfolio-slider-1` and then populated with the correct file info.

How can I write a loop that creates an extra number of slides based on the value of `numberSlides`? I got this far but then I got stuck:

#### Unfinished code:

```
if(numberSlides > 1){
            console.log('creating '+numberSlides+' extra slides');
            // If more than 1, create the extra slides required
            counter = 2;
            counterMax = numberSlides;
            if (counter <= counterMax){ // make it loop?
              // something here?
            }
        }
```

Comment: At event, you create one additional slide (and so forth until max) or the maximum required directly?

Comment: Have you considered using a `for` loop, like `for(var i=1; i<numberSlides; i++)`?

Comment: @Pobe I need to create ALL required slides. So if 4 total slides, at event I need to create slide 2 & 3 & 4 (no.1 is there by default) and then load data into 2 & 3 & 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop. In this case, it would look something like this:

```
for(var i=1; i<numberSlides; i++){
  //append slide
}
```

The first statement of the for loop defines the variable that will be iterated. Since you already have one slider, the value is 1 instead of 0. The second statement is the test on when the loop will finish. As long as `i` is less than the number of slides needed, it will append a slide. Lastly, the `i++` increments `i` every time the loop executes the statement inside.

So setting `slideNumber` to `4` will loop the code 3 times, until `4<4 == false`.

Comment: Thanks, the loop seems correct however I don't seem to get the appendTo to work here, it just doesn't create any items `$('#portfolio-slide-'+i).appendTo('#portfolio-slide-'+i-1);`

Comment: To add, I need help working out how to append correctly as I don't know how to use `i` or `numberSlides` correctly to create the div `#portfolio-item-2` etc

Comment: There is an issue with your syntax in `appendTo`. The docs say that it adds the element on the _inside_ of the element you are adding to, so you need to change `'#portfolio-slide-'+i-1` to `#dorking-brewery`.

Comment: `i` is an integer (always), so you use that for the number in `id`. `numberSlides` is used exclusively for the loop.